# Error with AFNETWORKING

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, afnetworking

I try to install AFNETWORKING in my Objective-C application.

I have followed the instructions in this tutorial:
https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning

I have readden than "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager" was remplaced by "AFHTTPSessionManager" so:

I declared as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) AFHTTPSessionManager *manager;
```

Then I added in my init function:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
[self.manager setSecurityPolicy:policy];
```

I added my certificate in my project.

But when I run my code there is this error:

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=MY_URL, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=MY_URL}

I tried to set the certificate URL manually but the same error happen.

I checked on internet and I tried lots solutions but nothing worked. So does someone already fix this error please ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access the HTTP based URL?

Comment: Yes I am, do you have an idea ?

Comment: No offence, just to clarify - `MY_URL` is just a placeholder here on SO, right? Are you sure you are using a correct URL in your code? Maybe there is a typo there?

Comment: Yes, MY_URL is juste a placeholder ! Ok, I will verify it, you may be right. Thank you for your answer